# API integration in React but not call API properly

Tags: reactjs

I have my own API I'm using React typeScript and I want to show my API data into my react table but here proble is API call not properly response is shows undefined in console.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day Jayprakash,
I think you may attach few screenshots or code snippets to help you spot the issue.

Also, below is a link to show you steps for data fetching using fetchAPI.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-consume-rest-apis-in-react/

You could also use axios, or react-query, ....etc